# How do I update select option drop down list when a radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, php

Script that I am using for updating drop down list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:radio').change(function(){
            var val = $('input:radio:checked').val();
            $('#Select1').val(0)
            $('.storeCategory, .storeList').hide();
            $('.' + val).show();
        });
    });
```

Here I am using tail select.
And it's not updating the 2nd select list when 2nd radio button is selected or checked

```
<select name="selectstorename" id="Select1" name="Select1" multiple class="select-store-move" required="">
                            <?php if($storelist){
                                foreach ($storelist as $key => $storecat) {
                            
                                    echo '<option  class="storeList" value="'.$storecat->store_id.'">'.$storecat->store_name.'</option>';                                 
                                }
                            } ?>
                            <?php if($catStore){
                                foreach ($catStore as $key => $catstore) {
                            
                                    echo '<option  class="storeCategory" value="'.$catstore->cat_id.'">'.$catstore->cat_name.'</option>';                                 
                                }
                            } ?>
                        </select>
```

Two radio buttons

```html
<div class="radio-border storeCategoryRadioSelection">
                        <input type="radio" name="activateCoupon" type="radio" id="myRadio1" value="storeCategory">
                        <label for="myRadio1"> Store Category Wise</label>
                        <div id="user-selection-paragraph">
                            <span class="text-small">
                                radio description.
                            </span>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-border storeWiseRadioSelection">
                        <input type="radio" name="activateCoupon" type="radio" id="myRadio2" value="storeList">
                        <label for="myRadio2"> Store Wise</label>
                        <div id="user-selection-paragraph">
                            <span class="text-small">
                                radio description.
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It would help if we could see the HTML for the radio buttons

Comment: _"...not updating the 2nd variable2 list"_ - what exactly do you expect to happen here? Do you just want to select a specific option based on the radio value or are you actually looking to replace all the options in the select?

Comment: i want to update options when one of the radio button is checked

Comment: Given a minimal sample of what the generated option data would look like, your code appears to work ok - here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w23q6Lh0/ . If it's somehow not working for you, you'll need to a) clarify the problem, and/or b) show a real sample of generated `<option>` data so we can see whether there is something specific about the data which is causing a problem.

Comment: Basically <option> is just printing the Stores names or Store Category names with the help of foreach statements. And when I use tail select for select option it creates its own class for <option> tag so I can't add it manually it doesn't show in browser inspect if I add it manually.. Maybe this will clear something..thanks for your time though.

Comment: Sorry what is "tail select" exactly? And you still didn't entirely explain the problem.

Comment: https://github.pytes.net/tail.select/
may this helps...and <option> data as below.
```html
<select name="selectstorename" multiple="" class="select-store-move" required="" data-select-hidden="0" data-tail-select="tail-1" style="display: none;">
<option value="11">Fruitwale.Com</option>
<option value="27">Special fast food store</option>
<option value="31">Mybasket Store</option>
<option value="32">Delhi Kirana Store</option>
<option value="33">Ekbote Furniture</option>
<option value="34">fasion cloth wear</option>
<option value="35">Grossify</option>
```